# Enable UTF8 in Python comint processes

Tags: comint, utf-8

I'm trying to fix a Python3 script that breaks while processing a string containing Japanese characters, "出典データ".

While debugging, I get the following error when printing the string from an Emacs comint (e.g. `M-x shell`):

```
(Pdb) my_file
*** UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 39-43: character maps to <undefined>
```

Doing the exact same from Powershell, independent of Emacs, the string prints without error (albeit rendered incorrectly with little boxes).

I'm able to copy and paste the string into the buffer without issue.

I've tried setting the output and input to "utf-8" using `set-buffer-process-coding-system` and this appears to have no effect.

**Edit**

The first two sections of `mule-diag` run in the shell buffer gives:

```
########################################
# Section 1.  General Information
########################################

Version of this emacs:
  GNU Emacs 28.1 (build 2, x86_64-w64-mingw32)
 of 2022-04-21

Configuration options:
  --with-modules --without-dbus --with-native-compilation --without-compress-install CFLAGS=-O2

Multibyte characters awareness:
  current-buffer: t

Current language environment: UTF-8

########################################
# Section 2.  Display
########################################

Window-system: w32

The font and fontset of the selected frame are:
     font: -outline-Lucida Console-normal-normal-normal-mono-17-*-*-*-c-*-iso8859-1
  fontset: -outline-Lucida Console-normal-normal-normal-mono-17-*-*-*-c-*-fontset-auto2
```

Comment: Visit the python file, put the cursor on the first character of the string and say `C-u C-x =`. What does emacs say about the character? Check the rest as well. In your shell buffer, what does `M-x mule-diag` say? The first two sections should be enough: the output is long.

Comment: There's no file associated with the buffer.  I've started `M-x shell` and then run the script using `python my_script.py`.  There is a hardcoded `breakpoint()` which I then use to step through using the comint.  The string comes from a file path entered by users at run-time, either passed in or selected from a QFileDialog.

Comment: What happens if you hardwire the string into a print statement in a python program and then run that program in your shell buffer? Does that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is purely a Python problem that has nothing to do with Emacs. Read the [documentation for sys.stdout](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdin):

```
On Windows, UTF-8 is used for the console device. Non-character devices 
such as disk files and pipes use the system locale encoding (i.e. the
ANSI codepage).
```

Emacs comint mode naturally uses pipes to send input to Python and get output back for display in the buffer, so Python sees that its output is not the console and chooses an encoding system other than UTF-8.

Your program should check the encoding of stdin and stdout and ensure that it is UTF-8, but you’ll have to figure that out on your own. The means are probably documented on that same page.

Comment: Good call.  I got it to work using the `-X` flag mentioned on the page you linked.  Maybe we could include that in the body of your answer for posterity?